# launch java desktop application without eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have a game program written in java with the IDE eclipse. The program is deployed on a server and can be launched by an applet in a browser. I can also launch the game within my eclipse. I have a applet.launch file like this to do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/FW/java/src/game/client/be/fw/game/client/GameApplet.java"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="1"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.debug"/>
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.run"/>
</listAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_HEIGHT" value="200"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_NAME" value=""/>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_PARAMETERS">
<mapEntry key="language" value="FRANCAIS"/>
</mapAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_WIDTH" value="200"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER&quot; javaProject=&quot;FW&quot; path=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry id=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.classpathentry.defaultClasspath&quot;&gt;&#10;&lt;memento exportedEntriesOnly=&quot;false&quot; project=&quot;FW&quot;/&gt;&#10;&lt;/runtimeClasspathEntry&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/FW/build/jars/cards.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/FW/build/jars/icones.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="be.fw.game.client.WhistApplet"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="FW"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

I want to be able to launch the game with a desktop launch icon. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In the Eclipse menu bar, go to File, select Export... and export it as a Runnable Jar.

Comment: No it doesn't work like that. The client side of the program is composed of different jars. The server side is on a server. I am able with the script above to launch the client side of the program within eclipse. If I make an executable jar like you suggest, I think I zip the whole program (client side and server side). Someone else an idea?

Comment: You have absolute power over what goes into a jar and what doesn't, could you better explain your program's structure please ?